# Undefined method `filter' for array

Tags: ruby, replit, ruby-2.5

So I am trying to solve a class problem/homework on repl.it, in ruby, and this is the error listing I'm given.

```
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]

undefined method `filter' for [{:r=>1, :c=>0}, {:r=>0, :c=>1}]:Array
(repl):61:in `escape'
(repl):79:in `maze_escape'
(repl):82:in `<main>'
```

I can't understand the reason for this, because filter is clearly a method that is defined for the class Array, as a part of Ruby core, [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-filter)

Comment: What code causes this error?

Comment: @Amadan The entire information to recreate the error is there. Look at the first snippet that shows the error information.

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t think of checking the version either.

Comment: While your problem is Ruby version-related, it is not related to the fact that you are using repl.it and I can't see anyone searching on "ruby-2.5", so I suggest you remove those two tags. "ruby" alone is sufficient. "ruby-2.5" does no harm but the "repl.it" tag could cause some readers with repl.it issues to waste time reading your question. Not a big deal, obviously.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using ruby version `2.5.5`.

`Array#filter` was [added to ruby version `2.6.0`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_0/NEWS).

However, the method is merely an alias for `Array#select` - so you can use this instead, if you are unable to upgrade the ruby version right now.

Note: The documentation you linked to is for ruby version `2.6.3` (i.e. the latest, at the time of writing). You can see the (*almost*-identical) documentation for version `2.5.5` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.5/Array.html).

Comment: Thanks. This worked. The version difference didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using ruby 2.6?`filter` is only available in ruby 2.6.

If you are using version prior than 2.6, use `select` instead of `filter`.